# How do I move an graphic to the top of a frame?

Tags: beamer, graphics

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\definecolor{links}{HTML}{2A1B81}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor=,urlcolor=red}

\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
\usefonttheme{structuresmallcapsserif}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{CAES/EPI Presentation Template}
\setbeamercolor{author}{fg=yellow}
\author{David Solan - Energy Policy Institute, Director\\David Koehler - Energy Policy Institute, Assistant Director}
\setbeamercolor{date}{fg=yellow}
\date\today



\begin{document}

{\usebackgroundtemplate
{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{caestitlepage}}
\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\section*{Outline}

{\usebackgroundtemplate
{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{caessubslide}}
\begin{frame}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \frametitle{Contents}
    \tableofcontents
\end{multicols} 
\end{frame}

\section{WEPRC 2012}
\subsection{WEPRC 2012 Overview}
    \begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
    \frametitle{WEPRC 2012 Overview}
    \item \hyperlink{PARTICIPANTS}{\beamergotobutton{Participants}} 
    \item \hyperlink{PRESENTERS}{\beamergotobutton{Presenters}}
    \item \hyperlink{KEYNOTESPEAKERSPONSOR}{\beamergotobutton{Keynote Speaker/Sponsors}}
    \end{itemize}
    \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=0.4\textheight,keepaspectratio]{2012weprclayedonmap}
    \end{center}
    \end{frame}

\subsection{Participants}
    \begin{frame}[label=PARTICIPANTS]
    \frametitle{Participants}
        \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=0.4\textheight,keepaspectratio]{epiwelcome}
    \end{center}
    \end{frame}

\subsection{Presenters}
\begin{frame}[label=PRESENTERS]
\frametitle{Presenters}
\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth,height=.7\textheight,keepaspectratio]{2012weprcpresenters}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
WEPRC PRESENTER LIST
\end{frame}

\subsection{Keynote Speakers/Sponsors}
\begin{frame}[t,label=KEYNOTESPEAKERSPONSOR]
\frametitle{Keynote Speakers/Sponsors}
\includegraphics[scale=.4]{2012weprcsponsors}%
\includegraphics[scale=.4]{2012weprckeynotespeaker}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try adding `\vfill` before `\end{frame}`?

Comment: yes, did not work.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `t` option for the frame:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t,label=KEYNOTESPEAKERSPONSOR]
\frametitle{Keynote Speakers/Sponsors}
\includegraphics[width=.48\linewidth]{2012weprcsponsors}\hfill%
\includegraphics[width=.48\linewidth]{2012weprckeynotespeaker}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The line

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}
```

simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; delete it in your actual document.

Also, instead of usinf scale=, I would suggest you to control the size using `width=<length>` or `height=<length>` as I did in my example.

Comment: That did not work. Still in bottom left of frame.

Comment: @user28552 Sorry, but simply saying "did not work" is useless; as you can see in my example, it works. If it's not working for you, please edit your question and add a *complete* example (not just snippets) allowing us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ok, I'm still new to this.  Thanks for being patient.

Comment: @user28552 Hmmmm... your code is far from minimal. Anyways, since we don't have the actual images you are using, it's hard to tell; I did some tests with some of my images and everything worked as expected; try my last advise: instead of `scale`, use something like `width=.48\linewidth` and see if this helps.

Comment: How about this, how would I center align the first image instead?

Comment: @user28552 do you mean the one in the frame labeled with `label=PARTICIPANTS`?

Comment: Correct, the last frame.

Comment: @user28552 I am confused. Now you want to center just the first image? and center it how, vertically, horizontally, both? And where should the other image go?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Vertically center the first image only.  Keep the 2nd image as is.

Comment: @user28552 can you upload elsewhere (and then provide a link) the actual images for testing? If that's not possible, then can you please tell me the actual size of the images?